# jQuery plugin: How to access elements where plugin was applied from secondary function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, javascript

I am new to jQuery and I am building a custom plugin, it looks something like this (pseudo-code):

```
jQuery.fn.myPlugin = function( options )
{

    var defaults = {
        interval : 5 * 1000
    };

    var interval_handler = setInterval( function( ) { update( ); }, interval );

    var opts = $.extend( defaults, options );

    return this.each( function( ){
        $( this ).bind( event, stuff );
    });

    function update( )
    {
        if ( condition == true )
        {
            clearInterval( interval );

            // unbind() foreach element the plugin has used
        }
    }
}
```

My question is:

How can access all the elements the plugin has used on `return this.each(...)` from the `update( )` function?

*Also, is the way im using functions inside the plugin correct? I didn't know how to do it so I just tried that and it worked.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put it in a variable:

```
var elements = this;
```